# Когда частицу "таки" можно заменить частицей "то"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, частица-таки

Существует две частицы: ***ТО*** и ***ТАКИ***, которые в некоторых случаях могут заменять друг друга.

Например, некий персонаж провинился, и об этом разговор:

***— Что он там такого сделал-таки?***

Фраза кажется надуманной, даже фонетика выглядит странно: ***та, та, та.*** И какой смысл имеет повтор: ***там, такого, таки***?  И наконец, какой смысл имеет сама частица ***ТАКИ***?

А если сказать так:

***— А что он там сделал-то?***

Будет ли утерян какой-нибудь **оттенок смысла?**  (Хотя для **улучшения дикции** фраза вполне подходящая.)

**-ТО, частица.** 1. Употр. для подчёркивания и выделения в предложении слова, к которому относится. Я-то понимаю. Ночь-то какая тёплая! Слушать-то слушал, да ничего не понял.

**-ТАКИ, частица.** Разг. Тем не менее, всё же, однако. Дождался-таки свободы.

Answer (score 3):

Я могу предположить **следующее.**

Частица ***ТО*** является **выделительной и усилительной**,  а частица ***ТАКИ*** — **выделительной и уступительной.**

В общем случае разница **существенная**, но если **выделительная** функция является **основной,** то частицы заменяют друг друга. Именно это мы видим в приведенном примере, где **нет уступительного** значения.

Поэтому должна быть **культура речи**, хотя бы на форуме лингвистов и любителей **изящной словесности**.

**Каждое слово** должно быть на месте, а иначе мы вконец испортим свое **восприятие** правильного или неправильного после общения с такой грамматикой и **стилистикой**.